# Bootstrap css applied for a particular textbox is applying to entire page - css

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a simple table like as in the first pic. Now I have to add a datetime picker for a textbox (start). For that I added a css (DateTimePicker/bootstrap.min.css) for the calendar, time format and all. But now seems like the same css is applied to all the other controls on the page. How can I restrict the css applied to particular textbox only? My code is here.

```
  <link href="DateTimePicker/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="DateTimePicker/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DateTimePicker/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DateTimePicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DateTimePicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                weekStart: 1,
                todayBtn: 1,
                autoclose: 1,
                todayHighlight: 1,
                startView: 2,
                forceParse: 0,
                showMeridian: 1
            });
       
             });
    </script>
    <style>
        table.noun {
                font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
                font-size:20px;
                color: blue;
                background: white;
             }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="dialog" style="background-color:white;vertical-align: middle;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="background-color: white; vertical-align: middle;">
        <div>
              <table Class="noun">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <div class="header">New Class</div>
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> <td>
                   <asp:Label ID="lbl_staffname" runat="server" Text="Teacher"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_staff" runat="server" Text="XXXX" ></asp:TextBox>                 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_student" runat="server" Text="Student"></asp:Label>
                      <br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_student" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" class="dropdownList" AutoPostBack="true">
                         <asp:ListItem Value="1">AAAAA</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">BBBB </asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>           
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_ROLL" runat="server" Text="Roll No"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_roll" runat="server" Text="40" ></asp:TextBox>                     
                </td>        
                      <td>
                     <asp:Label ID="lbl_starttime" runat="server" Text="Start"></asp:Label><br />
                <div id="datetimepicker1" class="controls input-append date form_datetime" data-date="" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm P" data-link-field="dtp_input1">           
        <asp:TextBox ID="tb_startdate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" value="" />                   
                </td>                             
            </tr>   
                  </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Default design:
[image]

After applying the css for time picker:
[image]

Comment: I would not add the complete bootstrap css and js for 1 textbox. Better use a separate jquery datepicker plugin.

Comment: Did you used any one?

Comment: https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: Is a good one. You can disable the timepicker part if needed. And lots of more options.

Comment: To include a hole css framework for a date picker is bad practice but possible. Please follow this link to find out how.  https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-apply-bootstrap-to-only-one-div-without-affecting-the-entire-website-style-And-if-so-what-are-some-possible-ways-to-do-it